# What would you call a person who is friendly on the outside but from the inside is plotting something against the one he is acting nice to?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I type this question in the Google it shows the name of some disease...and I don't want that...I am looking for a word that can discribe him...if not then atleast some adjective to receive his personality, e.g- cunning

Comment: ***two-faced*** adjective


1 : DOUBLE-DEALING, FALSE

Comment: My favorite for this is _perfidious_. I find it goes deep and carries a connotation of full-out character condemnation, not confined to just a single act. For a more contemporary term, there is _back-stabber_.

Comment: There is a specific phrase that applies to this situation but not the one in the duplicate, which is "wolf in sheep's clothing".

Answer (score 1):

Treacherous is what comes to mind first. But also devious, two-faced, passive-agressive, Depending in degree and context.
I’m sure there are more. Take those words and check a Thesarus for more based on those words, if you need others.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. I like your answers: treacherous, devious, two-faced, and passive-aggressive. Since the OP may not be familiar with these terms and their nuances, would you please provide references (such as dictionary definitions)?